# undefined event in a drag and drop javascript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, undefined

The task I want to perform is to drag a picture from one div into another a canvas of another div. Both canvas and picture are created by javascript. Been struggling to get this work work. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>dad-test</title>
<body>
<div  id="spaltemu"> </div>
<div id="umain"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}
function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}
function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  alert(data);
}
//add a image (bild) to umain and aloow it to be dragged
    let divUM = document.getElementById('umain');
    let karteverd = document.createElement('img');
    karteverd.src = 'bild.jpg';
    karteverd.draggable = true;
    karteverd.ondragstart= 'drag(event)';
    divUM.appendChild(karteverd);

// create a canvas in spaltemu and allow the image (bild) to be dropped here
    var spkart = document.getElementById ('spaltemu');
    var platzhalter = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = platzhalter.getContext('2d');
    ctx.ondrop = drop(event);
    ctx.ondragover = 'allowDrop(event)';
    spkart.appendChild(platzhalter);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Executing the code below the debugger shows "TypeError: ev is undefined" in drop(ev); Can anybody give me a hint what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot the quotes when assigning `ctx.ondrop`.

Comment: thank you a lot. silly mistake - sorry for bothering you -